# Capturing the output from python script which called through powershell

Tags: python, powershell, tfs

Currently i have the stuff in place in my TFS like below :

- TFS Job calls powershell *script1*
- powershell *script1* calls powershell *script2* (having module)
- Powershell module calls the python script using Start process which returns the standard output through `-RedirectStandardOutput`. And the same is capturing/returning to TFS.

But the thing is all the output from python script is returning in one go and not able to get the line by line logs to TFS instantly.

Can anyone suggest if there is way to return the output from python script to TFS instantly line by line logs?

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to make the Start-Process call asynchronously either using Jobs or Runspaces, and then constantly monitor the job/runspace child session for output to display.